# rospack package not found error

Tags: ros, catkin-package, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a package in catkin workspace and put a publisher.py node inside the src directory of package which worked fine. Then i added another node subscriber.py node and used catkin_make to build. Now when I try to run any of the nodes or find package i am getting above error. Am I missing any step ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232511/rospack-package-not-found-error/) by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Am I missing any step ?

```
source /path/to/your/workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

perhaps?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddhesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26663/siddhesh/) on 2016-04-21**:
Thanks it worked, Do I need to type it before running every node ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-21**:
No, not every node. Every bash session (or whatever shell you're running). But if you would want, you could add that line to your `.bashrc`. You'll get errors if that file doesn't exist though.